# Does Windows cache the .NET version used by an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I made the mistake of trying to deploy a program built with .NET 4.7.1 on a machine that didn't have that version of the .NET framework installed. It popped the following error message:

[image: .NET framework error message]

Since installing a new .NET framework requires a reboot, I don't want to go that route yet. So I tried downgrading the target framework to 4.6.1... but I still get the same error!

I verified that the assembly was compiled targeting the 4.6.1 framework:

[image: screenshot of framework version]

As a test, I renamed the assembly VueLinks2.exe and it started just fine.

The only thing I can think of is that Windows "remembers" what framework is associated with an assembly. Is that correct? Is it possible to undo that and downgrade an app to a previous version without renaming the file?

Comment: Is there a `VueLinks.app.config` that includes framework settings, by any chance? `VueLinks2` woudn't match that.

Comment: Ahh there is! Even though it got changed in the app.config, I must have failed to copy the resulting vuelinks.exe.config over to the deploy directory. What a rookie mistake! If you'll write that up I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no cache. Deciding what framework to use is a combination of the `<requiredRuntime>` (legacy) and [`<supportedRuntime>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element) elements in the `[exe].app.config` and the assembly's framework version if those are not supplied. Renaming the executable will cause the `[exe].app.config` to no longer be matched.